# Minicart is empty on Brand page in magento

Tags: php, magento

When I add any product to cart it also updates the minicart placed in header. Minicart on every page shows me correct number of products added but when I browse to brand page i.e. mysite.com/adidas minicart shows "Your cart is empty"

Why this happening why minicart is not showing added products on brand page although all other pages shows me correct number of products added to cart.

I am really screwed please help me!

Comment: Did you have get installed full cache on your store ? I had experience with that it was conflicting it

Comment: Yes I did ... @sagarumaretiya

Comment: This is the causes issue on your Brand page in magento. just dig it out more you will get your solution

Answer (score 0):

I found that Shop by brand extension is belong to **magestore** (http://www.magestore.com/magento-shop-by-brand-extension.html) so I contact them and they said that this is a bug in their plugin. At last this problem has been resolved by applying a patch given by **magestore**.